# Bigquery REGEX getting numbers only that followed by certain text (unit)

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

i have tables that contain product name. i want to extract the numbers only from it. but only numbers followed by the unit (certain text) ex: gr, kg, ml, pcs.

```
product name         | Extracted
milk 30ml            | 30
Cigarette 20pcs      | 20
Sugar 50gr           | 50
1990 chocolate 10gr  | 10
```

Is there any way to only getting number that followed certain text we desired? i just know how to extract numbers only but the last product will getting error.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` here with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT product, REGEXP_EXTRACT(product, r'([0-9]+)(?:l|ml|gr|g|mg|[a-z]+s)\b') AS Extracted
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: is there any way that the string after numbers is a certain text only not any alphabet? product named "RX2k 20gr" will return error instead of 20

Comment: Provide all the suffixes you want to accept.

Comment: suffixes: [l, ml, gr, g, mg, 's]. the number always followed by these suffixes without spaces 16g or 20's